Instance scaling up randomly with no random node using geometry nodes
I've been trying to make some capsules distribute on a surface, and it seems to be working fine, but the scale is weirdly skewed, as some of the instances are scaled differently from my actual model, and I have no clue because I'm not doing anything with the scale.


You have to apply scale : CTRL+A > Apply Scale.


I'm not doing anything with the scale.

Yes, you are. The object is not at 1, 1, 1 scale: 
You even have this non-default scale being expressly used in the geometry nodes, which I think is squaring it and making the deformation worse. 
Try cutting that link (I believe it’s Ctrl + LMB and drag over the wire), or I think you could possibly invert the vector to un-scale the instances instead of double-scaling them (not sure if there’s a node to do this), or just apply the scale to the main object so that it is 1, 1, 1.
